# Caching bitmap code confusing

Tags: android

Can anyone comment out this code to give me a better idea of whats going on in this code?

Thanks.

```
private void putBitmapInDiskCache(Uri url, Bitmap avatar) {     
File cacheDir = new   File(context.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");   
File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+url.hashCode());    
 try {      
  cacheFile.createNewFile();       
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);      
 avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);       
 fos.flush();       
 fos.close();    
 } catch (Exception e) {      
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);     
}  
 }
```

To read them it's similar:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);   
Bitmap local = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/**
 * Write bitmap associated with a url to disk cache
 */
private void putBitmapInDiskCache(Uri url, Bitmap avatar) {     
    // Create a path pointing to the system-recommended cache dir for the app, with sub-dir named
    // thumbnails
    File cacheDir = new   File(context.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");   
    // Create a path in that dir for a file, named by the default hash of the url
    File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+url.hashCode());    
    try {      
        // Create a file at the file path, and open it for writing obtaining the output stream
        cacheFile.createNewFile();       
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile); 
        // Write the bitmap to the output stream (and thus the file) in PNG format (lossless compression)     
        avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        // Flush and close the output stream       
        fos.flush();       
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log anything that might go wrong with IO to file      
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);     
    }  
}
```

Second part:

```
// Open input stream to the cache file
fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile); 
// Read a bitmap from the file (which presumable contains bitmap in PNG format, since
// that's how files are created)
Bitmap local = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

Comment: Updated to include second part

Comment: In the second part, what goes in the CachFile part? How do i know whats the name of the cacheFile?

Comment: Presumably the name of the file is still the hash of the url, String cacheFile = "" + url.hashCode(); // "" + int is a shorthand for converting int to string

Comment: Could you possibly answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862270/how-to-integrate-this-cachebitmap-method-with-this-image-getter-code

Comment: @antlersoft im getting the following error when i try to run your code  java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)... any idea?

Comment: had to add the following lines of code.  if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdir();