# How to integrate this cacheBitmap method, with this image getter code?

Tags: android

How would i go about integrating this cache method..

```
public void putBitmapInDiskCache(Uri url, Bitmap avatar) {     
    File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");    
    File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+url.hashCode());     
    try {      
        cacheFile.createNewFile();       
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);    
        avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);      
                    fos.flush();       
        fos.close();     
    } catch (Exception e) {       
        Log.e("error", "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);    
    }
```

With this code....

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches(true);
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
        Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");

        /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
        i.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
```

EDIT: Gives me a syntax error

```
The constructor File(File, int) is undefined



                            Uri imageUri = new Uri(aURL);
                            File cachePath = new File(new File(myContext.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"), imageUri.hashCode()).exists();
                            if (new File(new File(myContext.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"), imageUri.hashCode()).exists())
                            {

                            } else {
```

EDIT2: Another syntax error

```
Cannot instantiate the type Uri

  Uri imageUri = new Uri(aURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call aURL.openConnection(), you want to check if the url is in the disk cache; if it is you can read it from there instead of proceeding with reading it from the URL.

```
URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
Uri imageUri = new Uri(aURL);
if (new File(new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"), "" + imageUri.hashCode()).exists())
{
    ...read from cache
} else {
... rest of read from URL code
```

After you've retrieved the bitmap, you want to cache it to disk:

```
                            bis.close();
                            is.close();
                            Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");
                            putBitmapInDiskCache(imageUri, bm);
```

Comment: On this line: if (new File(new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"), "" + imageUri.hashCode()).exists()) // note that I also removed the cachePath line, as it wasn't used

Comment: Getting syntax here Uri imageUri = new Uri(aURL);Uri cannot be instantiated

Comment: I was assuming that the Uri class in the caching code was the equivalent of java.net.URI; if it is not you need to figure out how to get one of those URI from a URL